# How do I validate a YYYYMMDD string is a date in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, date, date-format

The date is supplied as a string in the form: `20180503`

The function is supposed to validate that the entry is:

1. in the form `YYYYMMDD`
2. a valid date

The following code does not do the trick:

```
Function formatDateYYYYMMDD(dateStr As String, dateFormat As String) As String
    Dim strToDate As Date
    strToDate = CDate(dateStr)
     If IsDate(strToDate) Then
        formatDateYYYYMMDD= format(dateStr, dateFormat)
     Else
        formatDateYYYYMMDD= "Not a date"
     End If
End Function
```

Comment: Technically speaking, `20181013` is *not* a valid date in Excel.  . . .If this is for data entry *in Excel,* I'd **highly recommend** that you actually *do* use **valid** date entry formats, or else you'll be back here constantly with problems related to your non-standard date format.  **The best format to use is the [ISO-8601](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) international standard** of `yyyy-mm-dd`, which makes the most sense for several reasons.

Comment: Unfortunately the data comes from a feed. I am supposed to validate the entry is in YYYYMMDD format.

Comment: @ashleedawg - My understanding is that ISO 8601 does allow the separators to be removed, but it's not the preferred usage, and therefore `20181013` is part of the spec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps:

**edit**: original UDF changed as it would not flag certain invalid format dates.

```
Option Explicit
Function formatDateYYYYMMDD(dateStr As String, dateformat As String) As String
    Dim strToDate As Date
On Error GoTo invalidDate
If Len(dateStr) = 8 And _
    Left(dateStr, 4) > 1900 And _
    Mid(dateStr, 5, 2) <= 12 And _
    Right(dateStr, 2) <= 31 Then
        formatDateYYYYMMDD = Format(CDate(Format(dateStr, "0000-00-00")), dateformat)
    Exit Function
End If
invalidDate: formatDateYYYYMMDD = "Not a date"
End Function
```

The `On Error` will pick up invalid dates that otherwise meet the format criteria:  eg Sep 31, Feb 30

Comment: Thanks Ron. Works for my purpose!

Comment: @ibexy Sorry that I did not do sufficient troubleshooting.  The original did not sufficiently validate the format.  I have Edited my post to provide a more robust solution.  Please check it and post back if there are problems.

Comment: the previous version was also able to handle invalid date like 19902323. I have implemented the new version which works great too. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @ibexy but not 120808

Answer (score 2):

Interesting idea for a function. I've rewritten your code below to do exactly what you said. Function returns "Not a date" for 2018101a, 20181033, 201810300, otherwise returns date in formatted string. Note that you need to provide a valid string format and I did not handle that error. I assume there are no spaces at the end?

```
Function formatDateYYYYMMDD(dateStr As String, dateFormat As String) As String
Dim strToDate As Date
Dim day As Integer
Dim month As Integer
Dim year As Integer

On Error Resume Next

year = Left(dateStr, 4)
month = Mid(dateStr, 5, 2)
day = Right(dateStr, 2)

strToDate = DateSerial(year, month, day)
If Err.Number <> 0 Or Len(dateStr) <> 6 Then
    formatDateYYYYMMDD = "Not a date"
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
Else
    On Error GoTo 0
    formatDateYYYYMMDD = Format(strToDate, dateFormat)
End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

I fiddled with the code getting some directions from the guy's suggestion and it works now. Thanks, guys for all your input.

This is what I did

```
sValue = frmForm.txtSearch.Value

If IsDate(sValue) Then
    'do nothing
Else
sValue = Format(frmForm.txtSearch.Value, "DD-MM-YYYY")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a problem with the IsDate function.
It returns true for both 06.15.2023 and 15.06.2023.
So if your function is based on IsDate, you have to check that the day and month is not switched.

```
Function formatDateYYYYMMDD(dateStr As String, dateFormat As String) As String
Dim strToDate As Date
strToDate = CDate(Right(dateStr, 2) & "." & Mid(dateStr, 5, 2) & "." & Left(dateStr, 4))
 If IsDate(strToDate) Then
    If Format(strToDate, dateFormat) = dateStr Then
      formatDateYYYYMMDD = Format(strToDate, dateFormat)
    Else
      formatDateYYYYMMDD = "Not a date"
    End If
 Else
    formatDateYYYYMMDD = "Not a date"
 End If
```

End Function

Answer (score -1):

If the input date is always in this format(YYYYMMDD), you can write a custom code to convert it into a string that can be converted to date using CDATE.

Remember to convert month to name of the month, and year to four digit year. In this way you are explicitly defining the month, year and the remaining one as date, if you keep them as two digit numbers they may be interpreted differently on difference systems (when you convert them using CDATE)

I recommend this format DD-MMM-YYYY

In your code instead of

`strToDate = CDate(dateStr)`

You have to write a custom function

And in place of

`formatDateYYYYMMDD= format(dateStr, dateFormat)`

Return just the dateStr and set the format of the cell where it is returned to YYYYMMDD